# HighCharts(iOS) -How to show tooltip by default at only some positions

Tags: ios, swift, highcharts

**HighCharts(iOS):** How to show tooltip by default at only some positions by passing the index in swift, found the below example in javascript

```
let chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    events: {
      load() {
        this.tooltip.refresh(this.series[0].points[2]);
        this.tooltip.refresh(this.series[0].points[4]);
      }
    }
  },
  tooltip: {
    formatter: function() {
      return '3';
    }
  },
```

tried something like this

```
chart.events.load = tooltip.refresh(by: tooltipFunction)
```

can anyone convert the javascript to swift(iOS)

demo in javascript

https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/mqz3Ljy6/

Comment: Hi @OhStack, Accordint to this example: https://www.highcharts.com/demo/ios/dynamic-click-to-add, please try to use: `chart.events.load = HIFunction(jsFunction: "function () { this.tooltip.refresh(this.series[0].points[2]); }")`

Comment: @ppotaczek not working, syntax itself is wrong I guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a working code for the required result:

```
let options = HIOptions()

let chart = HIChart()
chart.events = HIEvents()
chart.events.load = HIFunction(jsFunction: "function() { this.tooltip.refresh(this.series[0].points[2]); this.tooltip.refresh(this.series[0].points[4]); this.tooltip.refresh(this.series[0].points[6]); }")
options.chart = chart

let tooltip = HITooltip()
tooltip.formatter = HIFunction(jsFunction: "function() { return '...'; }")
options.tooltip = tooltip

let plotOptions = HIPlotOptions()
plotOptions.column = HIColumn()
plotOptions.column.point = HIPoint()
plotOptions.column.point.events = HIEvents()
plotOptions.column.point.events.mouseOver = HIFunction(jsFunction: "function() { let tooltip = chart.tooltip; tooltip.update({ formatter: function() { return 'New content!' } }) }")
options.plotOptions = plotOptions

let column = HIColumn()
column.data = [4, 3, 5, 6, 2, 3, 7, 9, 12, 15, 2, 4, 6]
options.series = [column]
```

Answer (score 0):

Slight change in the accepted answer as graph need little time to load so setting timeout of 200ms, if data is more increase the time accordingly

```
let options = HIOptions()

let chart = HIChart()
chart.events = HIEvents()
chart.events.load = HIFunction(jsFunction: "function() { var self = this; setTimeout(function(){ self.tooltip.refresh(self.series[0].points[2]); }, 200); }")
options.chart = chart

let tooltip = HITooltip()
tooltip.formatter = HIFunction(jsFunction: "function() { return '...'; }")
options.tooltip = tooltip

let plotOptions = HIPlotOptions()
plotOptions.column = HIColumn()
plotOptions.column.point = HIPoint()
plotOptions.column.point.events = HIEvents()
plotOptions.column.point.events.mouseOver = HIFunction(jsFunction: "function() { let tooltip = chart.tooltip; tooltip.update({ formatter: function() { return 'New content!' } }) }")
options.plotOptions = plotOptions

let column = HIColumn()
column.data = [4, 3, 5, 6, 2, 3, 7, 9, 12, 15, 2, 4, 6]
options.series = [column]
```